# Yii Relation MANY_MANY: How to get attributes from relation table

Tags: yii, relation

I have three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(160) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `event` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `user_join_event` (
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `event_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`event_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_join_event_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_join_event_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`event_id`) REFERENCES `event` (`id`)
)
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3cUh.jpg)

`User` has relation with `Event` by `UserJoinEvent` :

```
'events' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Event', 'user_join_event(user_id, event_id)'),
```

I want to get `created` time in `user_join_event` table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot get additional attributes on a joining table with many_many relation but You can do this through has_many relation. Don't forget to make a model named UserJoinEvent from table user_join_event

Model User

```
'userJoinEvent' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'UserJoinEvent', 'user_id'),
'events' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Event', 'event_id', 'through'=>'userJoinEvent'),
```

Model UserJoinEvent

```
'event' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Event', 'event_id'),
```

Cotroller (example get the title of event and the date created from user with pk 1)

```
$model = User::model()->findByPk(1);
foreach ($model->userJoinEvent as $item) {
  echo $item->event->title;
  echo $item->created;
}
```